# Android TextView is not showing data on setText even if data is present

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm working on a small project where a user is shown his result after he tries to login and he already taken the quiz on my app.

[So i'm using a page like this to display result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBqq.jpg)

But i cannot display my score. This page also has an option to share your score which is working fine and displaying score.[Share option containing result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29FZi.jpg)

I'm attaching my XML and Java Code kindly please help me solve the issue that'll be great help.

Thanks & Regards

BugAdder

XML Code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center|top">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/login_score_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/score_result"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/login_score_text"/>

    <Button
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_share_button"
        android:text="@string/share_button"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/exit_button"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:id="@+id/login_exit_button"/>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java Code:

```
public class QuizLoginScore extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<ScoreItem> mScoreItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String mScore;
    private TextView mScoreTextView;
    private Button mShareButton;
    private Button mExitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score_login_quiz);
        mScoreTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_score_text);
        mShareButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_share_button);
        mExitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_exit_button);
        new FetchScoresTask().execute();
        mScoreTextView.setText(mScore);
        mExitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
                    finishAndRemoveTask();
                }else{
                    finishAffinity();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getScoreShareReport(mScore));
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getString(R.string.score_report_subject));
                i = Intent.createChooser(i,getString(R.string.send_report));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public String getScoreShareReport(String score){
        String result;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("QuizApp!").
                append("\n\n").
                append("I Just Scored").
                append(" \' ").
                append(score).
                append(" \' ").
                append("marks out of \' 100 \' in Latest Quiz on QuizApp!\nWhats your Score Huh?");
        result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }

    private class FetchScoresTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ScoreItem>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuizLoginScore.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Score");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while the score is being downloaded!");
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ScoreItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return new ScoreFetcher().fetchScoreItems();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ScoreItem> scoreItems) {
            mScoreItems = scoreItems;
            for(int i = 0; i < mScoreItems.size(); i++){
                if(mScoreItems.get(i).getUserId().equals(QuizLogin.mUserIdString)){
                    mScore = String.valueOf(mScoreItems.get(i).getScore());
                    break;
                }
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code should dislpay your score in the textView?

Comment: mScoreTextView.setText(mScore);

Comment: Why are setting text in onCreate?

Comment: What else should i do?

Comment: your mScore is still null. first out some value in mScore, then set to text view. that too in ui thread

Comment: mScore value is not null as it gets filled in AsyncTask(Background Thread) first. Kindly check my complete code first.Thanks :)

Comment: You call the AsyncTask and immediately sets the score which is null, before the AsyncTask finishes. Update the score from the onPoseExecute.

Comment: kindly learn some Java before saying that. Your mScore is assigned to textview first and then it is initialized in AsyncTask. Unfortunately Android doesnt support auto update of text view based on string variables, whenever you update a variable you have to set to textview again

Comment: I'm sorry Mohammed Asif i meant no disrespect and yes I'm a noobie and You sir solved my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thanks TDG ....  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mScore is set in a async task. so you must set text in onPostExecute. try following code:

```
public class QuizLoginScore extends AppCompatActivity {

        private List<ScoreItem> mScoreItems = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private String mScore;
        private TextView mScoreTextView;
        private Button mShareButton;
        private Button mExitButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.score_login_quiz);
            mScoreTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_score_text);
            mShareButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_share_button);
            mExitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_exit_button);
            new FetchScoresTask().execute();
            mScoreTextView.setText(mScore);
            mExitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
                        finishAndRemoveTask();
                    }else{
                        finishAffinity();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            mShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("text/plain");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getScoreShareReport(mScore));
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getString(R.string.score_report_subject));
                    i = Intent.createChooser(i,getString(R.string.send_report));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }

        public String getScoreShareReport(String score){
            String result;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("QuizApp!").
                    append("\n\n").
                    append("I Just Scored").
                    append(" \' ").
                    append(score).
                    append(" \' ").
                    append("marks out of \' 100 \' in Latest Quiz on QuizApp!\nWhats your Score Huh?");
            result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        }

        private class FetchScoresTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ScoreItem>> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuizLoginScore.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Score");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while the score is being downloaded!");
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected List<ScoreItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return new ScoreFetcher().fetchScoreItems();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<ScoreItem> scoreItems) {
                mScoreItems = scoreItems;
                for(int i = 0; i < mScoreItems.size(); i++){
                    if(mScoreItems.get(i).getUserId().equals(QuizLogin.mUserIdString)){
                        mScore = String.valueOf(mScoreItems.get(i).getScore());

            mScoreTextView.setText(mScore);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the set text part in ui thread runnable. everything else is perfect

Comment: Ok let me try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your mScore string in log to see if you are getting the data in logcat. Also try changing the color of your textview.  Also put your textview.settext() in onpostexecute(); method

Comment: Ok let me check :)

Comment: Ok also put your textview.settext(mScore); in onPostExecute method. Because when onCreate is called the first time your textview is always null.

Comment: My problem is solved by this  : mScore is set in a async task. so you must set text in onPostExecute.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Set text from `onPostExecute()`:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ScoreItem> scoreItems) {
            mScoreItems = scoreItems;
            for(int i = 0; i < mScoreItems.size(); i++){
                if(mScoreItems.get(i).getUserId().equals(QuizLogin.mUserIdString)){
                    mScore = String.valueOf(mScoreItems.get(i).getScore());
                    mScoreTextView.setText(mScore);

                    break;
                }
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Ferdous Ahamed for you answer :)